# WINE 64-bit .NET application crashes with .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit, wine

I encountered a problem with the 64-bit .NET Framework: my C# program is very simple:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    Debug.WriteLine("Debug Hello world!");
}
```

I installed the WINE-2.12 64-bit (the lastest development version) on CentOS 7 (3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64) and installed the .NET Framework 4.6.1 onto it. Before installing the .NET Framework, I removed wine-mono. I got the following error message when I tried to run the above program:

```
Hello world!

*Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_IndentSize()
at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.InitializeSettings()
at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.WriteLine(String message)
at ConsoleApplication3.Program.Main(String[] args)
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000000 at address 0x1aa460fd (thread 0009), starting debugger...*
```

The problem is with the line "Debug.WriteLine(...)". However, the same application compiled with 32-bit works well.

I found out that I got the similar error at other positions when I ran our in-house 64-bit .NET program, even if I don't use Debug.WriteLine(...), so I created the hello-world program to reproduce it.

My final goal is: run our 64-bit .NET application on a 64-bit WINE with .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Please someone instruct me how to overcome this problem?

Thanks.

Best regards,

/Kenny

Comment: The approach WINE chose has been problematic in many ways, so you are fully on your own, and if you cannot hack the source code you are stuck. Why not .NET Core?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also found out that the WINE cannot support 64-bit .NET application. I have a hard requirement to use .NET Framework due to libraries. .NET Core is unfortunately not an option for me.

Comment: A hard requirement on .NET Framework means a hard requirement on Windows. You cannot use any other operating system then.

Comment: May be you should try Wine 3 to get things working.